# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest')

Tags: android, flutter

**THIS IS A DEFAULT PROJECT WITH NO CHANGED CODE**

On Flutter Run:

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/comm
on/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/gen
eric/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/0
1
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/rep
ository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-im
g2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'D:\Android_Studio_Projects\flutter_testing\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for prop
erty 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full i
nsights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             44.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[On flutter run -v](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvZS9qR3h6l1lCS7tNQJ9BkLXoqD?e=adqeNU)

There are no issues on flutter doctor

I've tried many things and I just keep getting error after error, please help me out :(